# ASP.NET/C# running code between two pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I have a search textbox and button on my products page (`products.aspx`). The button, when clicked, compares the text in the textbox to the names of products in my database and shows the results in a repeater.

I have the search function working when the textbox, button and repeater are all on the same page however, ideally I wish to have the textbox and button on my products page and then the repeater to be shown on a search results page(`search.aspx`).

I understand that the button will need to redirect the user to search.aspx to show the results however my code doesn't run because the repeater does not exist on `products.aspx`. How do I get the button to run code on a different page?

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchWord = txtWord.Text;

    ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();

    var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchWord));

    Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx");

    rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
    rptrSearch.DataBind();

    litResults.Text = string.Format("<p>Search results for '{0}'. {1} Results found.</p>", txtWord.Text, results.ToList().Count);       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of that code belongs in the "Results.aspx". As you state, those controls don't exist on the "Products.aspx" therefore they cannot be accessed. The correct approach is to redirect to the "Results.aspx" and pass a query string (or form parameter) to the "Results.aspx" page with the query criteria.

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("~/Search.aspx?query={0}", searchWord));
```

Then on the Load event handler of your "Results.aspx" page write the following.

```
var searchWord = Request.Params[query] as string;
ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();
var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchWord));
rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
rptrSearch.DataBind()
litResults.Text = string.Format("<p>Search results for '{0}'. {1} Results found.</p>", searchWord, results.ToList().Count);
```

Answer (score 0):

For page to page communication, you can use Session.

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    Session["searchWord"] = txtWord.Text;

    Response.Redirect("~/Search.aspx");
}
```

Then on Search.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string searchWord = Session["searchWord"].ToString();

    ZaraEntities db = new ZaraEntities();

    var results = db.Products.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchWord));

    rptrSearch.DataSource = results.ToList();
    rptrSearch.DataBind();

    litResults.Text = string.Format("<p>Search results for '{0}'. {1} Results found.</p>", txtWord.Text, results.ToList().Count);

}
```